# How to test for serial correlation and ARCH effect in R package tsDyn?

Tags: r, autocorrelation, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model, arch

I recently started playing around with the [tsDyn package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tsDyn/) for R and successfully used it to estimate a bunch of VEC models and print their impulse responses (IRF) and error variance decompositions (FEVD). While I really like its intuitive and straightforward functions, one thing I have not been able to figure out is how to conduct diagnostic tests for a VEC model in tsDyn, specifically tests for serial correlation and ARCH effects?

I tried to convert a tsDyn-generated VEC model to a VAR in levels using the `vec2var()` function to apply the `serial.test()` and `arch.test()` functions from the [vars package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vars/), but this failed, presumably because `vec2var()` doesn't know how to handle classes produced by tsDyn. Since I am unsure whether this is the correct approach in the first place, I was hoping someone here may be able to give advice on the issue.

Here is what I did after loading `library(tsDyn)` and `library(vars)`:

```r
data(barry)
ve <- VECM(barry, lag=1, estim="ML")
serial.test(ve)
  Error in serial.test(ve) : 
  Please provide an object of class 'varest', generated by 'var()', or an object of
  class 'vec2var' generated by 'vec2var()'.
vec2var(ve)
  Error in vec2var(ve) : 
  Please, provide object of class 'ca.jo' as 'z'.
  In addition: Warning message:
  In if (!(class(z) == "ca.jo")) { :
    the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: You could include tags like `autocorrelation` and `garch` instead of `cointegration`; they might be more relevant.

Comment: This is Mat, I'm working on that package. Give me 1-2 days to answer as quite busy now, but in a nutshell you are right using vec2var() is the way to go, I'll check why/what it doesn't work. If oyu want in the meanwhile to provide small reproducible code, go ahead!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Richard, and thank you for looking into this personally, Mat. From what I understand, tsDyn's irf() and fevd() functions internally also use vec2var() in some way, I just wasn't able to figure out what they do differently as I don't have much experience digging into the code of contributed packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert yourself the VECM into a class recognised by urca, using the  function *vec2var.tsDyn* which is however (currently) not exported, so you need the unusual construction: *tsDyn:::vec2var.tsDyn*. And then can apply (most of) the vars/urca functions:

```
library(tsDyn);library(vars)
data(barry)
ve <- VECM(barry, lag=1, estim="ML")
ve_urca <- tsDyn:::vec2var.tsDyn(ve)
serial.test(ve_urca)
```

Gives you (in this case) the same result than using ca.jo directly:

```
ve_ur <- ca.jo(barry, K=2, spec="transitory")
var_ur <- vec2var(ve_ur)
serial.test(var_ur)
```

Best

Comment: Works like a charm. Exactly what I needed. Thanks, Mat!